# Javascript pushState - back / forward button not working as expected

Tags: javascript, pushstate

I'm able to successfully push a url into the browser history using javascript window.history.pushState.

I can click the browser's back and forward buttons and the urls change as expected. However, it does not actually bring back the previous page's content.

I can, manually, make this happen by clicking into the url bar and hitting the enter key, but I want to do this programmatically when the back or forward browser buttons are clicked.

I've already tried:

```
$(window).on("popstate", function() {
  alert("Back/Forward button was pressed.");
  window.location.reload(); // <-- brings back the page, but ruins the browser history stack. 
});
```

and

```
$(window).on("popstate", function() {
  alert("Back/Forward button was pressed.");
  window.location.href = window.location.href;
});
```

My function to pushState:

```
var qstring = "?q=mysearchquery";

function addURLToHistoryAPI(qstring) {
  if (window.history && window.history.pushState) {
    window.history.pushState(null, null, qstring);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to take care of rendering the content yourself using data pushed to history.

You should provide first argument to `pushState` function with data. This can be some page ID or plain HTML content. For example:

```
window.history.pushState(currentPageID, null, qstring);
```

or

```
window.history.pushState($("main").html(), null, qstring);
```

Then in the event listener, you can get access to this data and use it to render your page, for example:

```
$(window).on("popstate", e => {
    alert("Back/Forward button was pressed.");

    // "e.originalEvent.state" contains the data passed in the first argument
    console.log(e.originalEvent.state);
    $("main").html(e.originalEvent.state);
});
```